# iphone, I'm returing from a pushed view, which event do I reload my table data in?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm returning to my table view after selecting a new date range, I now need to reload the data in my table, which event do I do this in ?

Heres how I'm pushing my date selection sreen.

```
MyViewController *nextController = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.MyNavController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to go back to the last view you need:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and then in `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` of the tableviewcontroller you want to do:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: are you sure? Put an NSLog() in there just to make completely sure. It could be that you're not storing the data correctly or something.